# Selecting from presorted table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select neighbour of given row id, and it works:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name_id = (select max(name_id) from names where name_id < 5)
```

But I need to have row firstly selected by ascending 'name', and then, from this select neighbour, tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name_id = (select max(name_id) from 
            (select * from names ORDER BY name)
                                     )
names where name_id < 5
```

but this is not working though

Table 'names' have number 'name_id' and string 'name'

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Try to explain with words what you want to achieve, not with a query, please. It might be best to show some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in fact what do you want to get, but this part:

```
(select max(name_id) from 
        (select * from names ORDER BY name)
                                 )
```

Doesn't make sense in your example as it select max(name_id) from names table and it doesn't matter if it is ordered or not.

```
(select max(name_id) from names
                                 )
```

will give the same result. And your first query doesn't return neighbour with given id, but neighbour with max(name_id) from those whose id is < 5.

maybe you mean

```
SELECT name_id, name 
FROM (
SELECT name_id, name, RANK() OVER( ORDER BY name_id DESC) AS position 
FROM names)
WHERE position = 4;
```

? It should return the neighbour that has the 4th greatest name_id while

```
WHERE position < 5
```

should return 4 first greatest results.